# Is it possible to rename the application's group name in Django?

Tags: django, django-admin

For example, you have "Groups" and "Users" under "AUTHORIZATION AND AUTHENTICATION" (or something named like that). If you make a new app and register its model, it's gonna write out the name of the application. I want to rename that in the admin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that in the [**`verbose_name`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.verbose_name) of the `AppConfig`:

```
# app_name/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    verbose_name = _('My verbose name for the app')
```

In the `__init__.py` of the app, you then specify this as the default `AppConfig` for that app:

```
# app_name/__init__.py

default_app_config = 'app_name.apps.MyAppConfig'
```